# Android achartengine panning barchart

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, graphic

I am using achartengine graphic library for my android app. 
I draw barchart graphics on the screen below[image: barchart image]

When I pan barchart from right to left I get the second screen below

[image: barchart slide image]

My problem is that I dont want to show the left side of y axis during panning barchart.

I have challenge with source code of achartengine. Anybody helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using an old version of AChartEngine. I suggest you upgrade to 1.2.0.

Also, you probably created a transparent background, which could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi Dan,The problem was renderer.setApplyMarginBacgroundColor(false); I set this method true and I set margin color, than it is ok.